# Managing/Handling multiple widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

I apologize for my English in advance.

I am currently working on a mobile app, which is a simple game. The game is similar to SimonSays.  In my app there are 4 colored `Container`. The container are highlighted randomly and the player has to tap the highlighted one. Each `Container` is associated with a `GestureDetector`. The desired behavior of this collection is that only one may be tapped at a time (tapped is shown through changing the color of the container). The problem is that I cannot figure out how manage the container. 
My current approach is:

Utilizing the `Notification` class and notify the other containers (or an parent widget) that container was tapped.

I researched the topic, but could not find a good example how to utilize the Notification class. Below a code snippet of the current state is provided:

```
class _parentColorWidget extends State<colorWidget> {
  bool tapped = false;
  Color _initColor;
  Color color;
  _parentColorWidget(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
    this._initColor = color;
  }

  void onTap(bool tapped) {
    setState(() {
      if (tapped) {
        color = Colors.white70;
      } else {
        color = _initColor;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: _colorWidget(
        onChanged: onTap,
        context: context,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class colorWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  Color color;
  colorWidget(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
  _parentColorWidget createState() => _parentColorWidget(color);
}

class _colorWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  _colorWidget({@required this.onChanged, this.color, this.context});
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
  BuildContext context;
  Color color;
  bool tapped = false;

  void _onTap() {
    CustomNotification(current_widget: this).dispatch(context);
    onChanged(!tapped);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
        onTap: _onTap,
        child: new Container(
          color: color,
        ));
  }
}
```

I generated four widgets from this code. The managing through a parent widget is derived from an example I found on the official flutter documentation.

How do I use the notifications to identify which `container widget` is tapped or more precisely, if the correct `container` was tapped  ?

Thanks for all answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `Notification` then you dispatch some identifier, for example `color` value to parent. If you passing down callbacks, then this information can be encoded in callback it self, for example like this:

```
class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
   String selectedColor;

   Widget build() {
      return Stack(children: ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'].map((final color) =>
          Child(
            color: color,
            tapped: selectedColor == color,
            onTap: () { 
              setState(() {
                 selectedColor = color;
              })
            }
          )
      ]).toList());
   }
}
```

with this technique it's impossible to select 2 colors at same time, because selected color is tracked only in `selectedColor` and everything else is recomputed based on it's value.

And I would recommend to sticking to 1 way of how you pass calls to parent widgets, so either through callbacks or notifications and not both in single callback:

```
  void _onTap() {
    CustomNotification(current_widget: this).dispatch(context);
    onChanged(!tapped);
  }
```

For what you are doing I think callbacks should be enough to achieve everything.

Some tips to make code better:

1. Follow naming conventions, class names should be upper case
2. Don't pass around unnecessary information. In your code `onChanged(!tapped)`, here `!tapped` is unnecessary because this value was passed down from the parent. So when you pass this value up in the parent widget you will have 2 sources for same peace of information. Avoid having access to same information from more than 1 place - this just makes it easier to introduce state related bugs.
3. `class colorWidget extends StatefulWidget {` I don't see any reason for this widget to be stateful. Avoid having too many state widgets - better have one state controller with centralized game-play state & logic, and then pass down the information to stateless widgets. Especially avoid having 2 or more state widgets that need to have synchronized state between them. Single piece of information should have only 1 stateful widget that tracks & controls it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, took me awhile but a very smart and smooth solution